# Не запускается LocalDb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-localdb

Установил sql express 2016. Но не могу подключиться не только к localdb но и к именованному экземпляру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для LocalDb должно работать `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`. А для полноценного сервера `.\SQLExpress`. Не?

Comment: @Alexender Petrov но тем не менее компоненты установлены. Но не запущены и в конфигураторе пусто

Answer (score -1):

Так подключайтесь по имени экземпляра. 
А к локальному инстансу через ".".